KeyError: 'type' in a websocket_receive
I have two different apps in my Django project. While the first one (the one with the error raising consumers.py) works fine on its own, the second one keeps raising this:
\chat\consumers.py", line 29, in websocket_receive
    if event['type'] == 'message':
KeyError: 'type'

chat\consumers.py:
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer, AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from chat.models import Message, Thread, UserSetting
import json
from rich.console import Console
console = Console(style='bold green')


online_users = []
class WebConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.me = self.scope['user']
        self.room_name = str(self.me.id)

        online_users.append(self.me.id)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept',
        })

        console.print(f'You are connected {self.room_name}')

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        event = json.loads(event['text'])
        #console.print(f'Received message: {event["type"]}')

        if event['type'] == 'message':
            msg = await self.send_msg(event)
            await self.send_users(msg, [self.me.id, self.them_user.id])
        elif event['type'] == 'online':
            msg = await self.send_online(event)
            console.print(online_users)
            await self.send_users(msg, [])
        elif event['type'] == 'read':
            msg = await sync_to_async(Message.objects.get)(id=event['id'])
            msg.isread = True
            await sync_to_async(msg.save)()

            msg_thread = await sync_to_async(Thread.objects.get)(message=msg)
            await self.unread(msg_thread, int(event['user']), -1)
        elif event['type'] == 'istyping':
            console.print(self.me, event)
            await self.send_istyping(event)

    async def websocket_message(self, event):
        await self.send(
            {
                'type': 'websocket.send',
                'text': event.get('text'),
            }
        )

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        console.print(f'[{self.channel_name}] - Disconnected')

        event = json.loads('''{
            "type": "online",
            "set": "false"
        }''')

        online_users.remove(self.me.id)
        msg = await self.send_online(event)
        await self.send_users(msg, [])

        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_name, self.channel_name)

    async def send_msg(self, msg):

        them_id = msg['to']
        self.them_user = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get)(id=them_id)
        self.thread = await sync_to_async(Thread.objects.get_or_create_thread)(self.me, self.them_user)
        await self.store_message(msg['message'])
        await self.unread(self.thread, self.me.id, 1)

        await self.send_notifi([self.me.id, self.them_user.id])
        return json.dumps({
            'type': 'message',
            'sender': them_id,
        })

    @database_sync_to_async
    def store_message(self, text):
        Message.objects.create(
            thread = self.thread,
            sender = self.scope['user'],
            text = text,
        )

    async def send_users(self, msg, users=[]):
        if not users: users = online_users

        for user in users:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                str(user),
                {
                    'type': 'websocket.message',
                    'text': msg,
                },
            )

    async def send_online(self, event):
        user = self.scope['user']
        await self.store_is_online(user, event['set'])
        return json.dumps({
            'type': 'online',
            'set': event['set'],
            'user': user.id
        })

    async def store_is_online(self, user, value):
        if value == 'true': value = True
        else: value = False

        settings = await sync_to_async(UserSetting.objects.get)(id=user.id)
        settings.is_online = value
        await sync_to_async(settings.save)()

    async def send_notifi(self, users):

        console.print(f'NOTIFI {users}')

        for i in range(len(users)):
            text = json.dumps({
                'type': 'notifi',
                'user': users[i-1],
                'sender': users[0]
            })

            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                str(users[i]),
                {
                    'type': 'websocket.message',
                    'text': text,
                },
            )

    async def unread(self, thread, user, plus):
        users = await sync_to_async(thread.users.first)()

        if(users.id != int(user)):
            thread.unread_by_1 += plus
        else:
            thread.unread_by_2 += plus

        await sync_to_async(thread.save)()

    async def send_istyping(self, event):
        text = json.dumps({
            'type': 'istyping',
            'set': event['set'],
        })

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            str(event['user']),
            {
                'type': 'websocket.message',
                'text': text,
            },
        )

room\consumers.py:
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from .models import Room, RoomMessage

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(data)
        roommessage = data['message']
        username = data['username']
        room = data['room']

        await self.save_message(username, room, message)

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': roommessage,
                'username': username
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': roommessage,
            'username': username
        }))

    @sync_to_async
    def save_message(self, username, room, message):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        room = Room.objects.get(slug=room)

        RoomMessage.objects.create(user=user, room=room, content=message)

I tried messing around with the views and models and whatnot to no avail
sorry for the massive codeblocks

so some of messages that you send don't have type but receiver expects them to have
